# JavaScript multiple object instances, cannot correctly access properties inside event handler

Tags: javascript, closures, dom-events

I have a working version of HTML5 drag & drop file uploader. I was editing the JS code to support multiple file uploads on same page. I came across with a problem  by trying to access "instance" properties in methods which are registered as events.

The problem is shown by the code below, in method `this.drop`.
The reason of existence of the `this.$$upload_self` property is to access data through this property. For example, I can't use `this` keyword inside `this.drop` function, because when event is raised, `this` not referring my "instance".

I'm not sure that by creating `$$upload_self` was a good idea.

The new instances area created like this:

```
  var recording_upload = new upload();
  recording_upload.init(recording_upload, ...);
```

Code of Drag & drop file upload:

```
    var upload = function() {
    this.$$upload_self = null;
    this.$drop = null;
    this.$status = null;
    this.$progress = null;
    this.maxNumberOfFiles = null;
    ...
    
    this.init = function (self, pUrl, maxNmbOfFiles, dropArea, progress, status) {
        $$upload_self = self;
        $$upload_self.postUrl = pUrl;
        $$upload_self.maxNumberOfFiles = maxNmbOfFiles;

        $$upload_self.$drop = $("#" + dropArea);
        $$upload_self.$progress = $("#" + progress);
        $$upload_self.$status = $("#" + status);

        $$upload_self.$drop.bind('dragenter', $$upload_self.enter);
        $$upload_self.$drop.bind('dragleave', $$upload_self.leave);
        $$upload_self.$drop.bind('drop', $$upload_self.drop);
    };
    
    this.enter = function (e) {
        $(e.target).addClass('hover');
        return false;
    };

    this.leave = function (e) {
        $(e.target).removeClass('hover');
        return false;
    };
    
    this.drop = function (e, _this) {
        $(e.target).removeClass('hover');
        var files = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;

        if (files.length > $$upload_self.maxNumberOfFiles) { // for example, here $$upload_self references always last instance...
            $$upload_self.displayErrorMessage('Error: You can only drop ' + $$upload_self.maxNumberOfFiles + ' file(s) at time.');
            return false;
        }
     ...
    };
    ...
}
```

Is there any workaround to solve this issue? I believe this maybe a common problem, but can't find nothing to solve this problem.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could ditch the `new` keyword altogether and use a fresh closure for each instance of `upload`.

EDIT: Updated to avoid potential clobbering of global `this`.

```
var upload = function(pUrl, maxNmbOfFiles, dropArea, progress, status) {
    return {
        postUrl: pUrl,
        ...
        drop: function(e) {
            ...
            if (files.length > this.maxNumberOfFiles) {
                this.displayErrorMessage(...);
            }
            ...
        },
        ...
    };
};

...

var someUpload = upload(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to search for a "scope". As an example see how it implemented in ExtJS.

Comment: This is not really a scope issue; it's an issue with the semantics of function calls and `this`.

Comment: This is a "scope" in terms of ExtJS. Not variable scope, but may be some context -- I don't know more correct universal word.

Answer (score 1):

In a modern browser you can do this:

```
  $$upload_self.$drop.bind('dragleave', $$upload_self.leave.bind($$upload_self));
```

For older IE versions you can do this:

```
  $$upload_self.$drop.bind('dragleave', function() { $$upload_self.leave(); });
```

Really the ".bind()" method of all Function objects in new browsers just creates a little intermediate function for you, essentially like the second example.  The [Mozilla docs page for ".bind()"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) has a very good block of code you can use as a "polyfill" patch for browsers that don't support ".bind()" natively.